# Счетчик с конца строки в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, int

У меня есть строковая переменная, в которой содержится число 15, позже 200,  1029

Также есть другая переменная, с названием `result = '00000'`

```
aa = '15'
result = '00000'
```

Как сделать так, чтобы значения 'аа' подставлялись в конец `result`, примеры:

```
aa = '15'
result = '00015'
```

```
aa = '200'
result = '00200'
```

Итак дальше, ещё раз повторюсь необходимо добавлять значения с конца, нужен как можно меньше код

Comment: str.rjust(width, fillchar=" ") Делает длину строки не меньшей width, по необходимости заполняя первые символы символом fillchar

Comment: @Интик `str.rjust() takes no keyword arguments`

Comment: result=aa.rjust(5, '0')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самая короткая запись алгоритма решения:

```
aa = '200'
result = '00000'
print(aa.zfill(len(result)))
```

Метод `zfill(width)` делает длину строки не меньшей `width`, по необходимости заполняя первые символы нулями.

Вывод:

```
00200
```

Answer (score 1):

Получилось решить так:

```
result = '00000'
a = '15'
result = result + a
print(result[len(a):]) # 00015
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Развёрнутый код выглядит так:

```
    aa = '15'
    result = '00000'
    result += aa  # добавляем aa в конец строки
    result = result[len(a):]  # убираем первые n символов (n=len(a)
```

Моя попытка упростить его:

```
    aa = '15'
    result = '00000'
    result = result.replace('0' * len(aa), aa[::-1], 1)[::-1]
```

Небольшое пояснение:

- Используем [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9452108) - заменяем первые n нулей(n = len(aa)) "перевёрнутым" `aa`, то есть создаем строку, обратную нужной.
- "Переворачиваем" строку.

Comment: Не стоит давать ссылки на фейковые QA сайты с автопереводами, уж лучше дать ссылку на оригинал.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, недавно начал пользоваться Стаковерфлоу.